# Static configuation of USB interface on linux

Tags: linux, usb

How can I make sure that devices connected to a port are always assigned the same 'usb0' & 'usb1' interface .

Comment: Why? Are you trying to add USB devices to fstab? If so there is a better way...

Comment: @Tim I am configuring static ip address for each device based on the their usb interface  and if devices reboot their usb interface changes.